# Jenkins on Windows 10 - How to set default shell to Ubuntu.exe

Tags: windows, shell, ubuntu, jenkins

I have a similar question to the one found here, but the answer doesn't work for me.
[Jenkins on Windows 10 with Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39351532/jenkins-on-windows-10-with-bash)

I'm trying to set up Jenkins on a windows 10 machine, with a pipeline job that will run various shell commands.  I'd like all the shell commands to run under the Ubuntu shell, which I have installed here:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.547]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\myname>where ubuntu.exe
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe
```

I've tried setting a few different values in the "shell executable" field in Jenkins' "configure system" section, such as:

```
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe
```

But that returns the error:

```
There's no such file: C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe
```

Other values I've tried include:

C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe
'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu.exe'
C:\windows\system32\bash.exe
'C:\windows\system32\bash.exe'

So far, it's still a no go.
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, any solution or workaround for this??